# Using XMLslurper to get inner data

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am fiddling with a stockticker app. I am using Google's service. So, I read their page and parse the XML. I can iterate through the xml but the problem is Google puts the actual information inside the tag. So, for the latest price I would iterate to this: < last data="30.32" />. But I cannot read the actual data part. I tried using @data like the groovy api says, but it just comes back blank. Here is my code:

```
def stockTicket(params) {
  def BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock="+params.url
  def stock_url = BASE_URL
    def url = stock_url.toURL().text
    stock_url = urlMaker(stock_url)

    def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stock_url.openStream()))
    String strTemp = ""
    strTemp = br.readLine()
    def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(url)
    render records.xml_api_reply.finance.last.@data.text()

}
```

Comment: do you have some example xml?

Comment: Yeah, sure. http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=aapl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need

```
records.finance.last.@data
```

the slurper already points to the root node